# Community detection with bipartite graph in igraph

Tags: igraph, bipartite

I have bipartite list (posts, word categories) with 1000 vertecies and want to use the fast and greedy algorithm for community detection, but I am not sure if I have to run it on the bipartite graph or the bipartite projection.

My bipartite list looks like this:

```
   post word
1   66  2
2   312 1
3   432 7
4   433 7
5   434 1
6   435 5
7   436 1
8   437 4
```

When I run it without a projection I have problems clustering in the second step:

```
### Load bipartie list and create graph ###
bipartite_list <- read.csv("bipartite_list_tnf.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
bipartite_graph <- graph.incidence(bipartite_list)
g<-bipartite_graph
fc <- fastgreedy.community(g) ## communities / clusters
set.seed(123)
l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g, niter=1000, coolexp=0.5) ## layout
membership(fc)
# 2. checking who is in each cluster
cl <- data.frame(name = fc$post, cluster = fc$membership, stringsAsFactors=F)
cl <- cl[order(cl$cluster),]
cl[cl$cluster==1,]

# 3. preparing data for plot
d <- data.frame(l); names(d) <- c("x", "y")
d$cluster <- factor(fc$membership)

# 4. plot with only nodes, colored by cluster
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, color=cluster))
pq <- p + geom_point()
pq
```

Maybe I have to run the communnity detection on a projection? But then I always get I failure because a projection is not a graph object:

```
bipartite_graph <- graph.incidence(bipartite_list)
#projection (both directions)
projection_word_post <- bipartite.projection(bipartite_graph)
fc <- fastgreedy.community(projection_word_post)
Fehler in fastgreedy.community(projection_word_post) : Not a graph object
```

I would be glad for help!

Comment: `projection_word_post` is a list of two graphs, one for posts, one for words. What exactly is wrong with the second code block?

Comment: Thank you. So I need to do the community detection on a specific projection like this right?: #create graph
bipartite_graph <- graph.incidence(bipartite_list)

#projection (both directions)
projection_word_post <- bipartite.projection(bipartite_graph)

#Run CD algorithm
fc <- fastgreedy.community(projection_word_post$proj1)

Comment: The problem with the second block adjusted to the new fast and greedy algortihm run on projection1 is now: cl <- data.frame(name = fc$post, cluster = fc$membership, stringsAsFactors=F)
Error in data.frame(name = fc$post, cluster = fc$membership, stringsAsFactors = F) : 
  Argumentes imply different quantity of rows: 0, 1356

Answer (score 1):

When you run without the projection the issue is at:

```
bipartite_graph <- graph.incidence(bipartite_list)
```

You need to reshape 'bipartite_list' before applying into `graph.incidence()` function. Use the below command

```
tab <- table(bipartite_list)
```

and rest of the steps are same

```
g <- graph.incidence(tab,mode=c("all"))
fc <- fastgreedy.community(g)
```